# ATM Machine Programming Challenge

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double balance=0;
    int withdraw = 0;
    double const bankCharges = 0.5;


    cin >> withdraw >> balance;

    if(withdraw%5==0 && balance>(withdraw+bankCharges))
    {
        cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << ((balance)-(withdraw+bankCharges)) << endl;
    }
    else if(withdraw%5!=0 || withdraw>balance)
    {
        cout << fixed <<setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
    }


    return 0;


}
```

The above code is created to address the below challenge

http://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

As you can see, my code is providing the correct answer. But the test engine says "wrong answer" !!!!! Why? Please help!

Comment: Add the `else` condition.

Comment: @sgar91: wow! Awesome! Thank you!!!!!!!! Please provide your answer as the "answer". I will mark it as solved!

Comment: what do you get when input:  120 120.50?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never leave the `if`, `else if` block without an `else` condition if there is even a slight possibility to reach there. Add the `else` condition to your code.

```
if(withdraw%5==0 && balance>(withdraw+bankCharges))
{
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << ((balance)-(withdraw+bankCharges)) << endl;
}
else if(withdraw%5!=0 || withdraw>balance)
{
    cout << fixed <<setprecision(2) << balance << endl;
}
else
{
   //Do something
}
```